# How to edit sending messages with Rsyslog?

Tags: rsyslog

I have a rsyslog server that sends messages.

I wonder, is it possible that I can edit any of the data I forward?

In other words, one of the logs I send includes the following information:

```
<13>Nov 29 08:00:00 localhost CEF: 0|212|656|1|1|Bot Access Control|4| fileId=739000180002315518 sourceServiceName=
```

And I would be interested in changing the host name, for example. From localhost to HOST01

```
<13>Nov 29 08:00:00 HOST01 CEF: 0|212|656|1|1|Bot Access Control|4| fileId=739000180002315518 sourceServiceName=
```

I have no control over where the logs are received, only the delivery.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [property replacers](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/property_replacer.html) working on the `msg` property, assuming this is where the string `localhost` is found.

Put in your `rsyslog.conf` or similar a line defining a *template* called, say, `newmsg`:

```
$template newmsg,"%timestamp% %programname% %msg:R,ERE,1:(.*) localhost --end% HOST01 %msg:R,ERE,1: localhost (.*)--end%\n"
```

To make this more readable here it is split over several lines, but you must use the above version:

```
$template newmsg,
 "%timestamp% %programname% 
  %msg:R,ERE,1:(.*) localhost --end%
  HOST01 
  %msg:R,ERE,1: localhost (.*)--end%
 \n"
```

This contains 2 uses of a replacer like this: `%msg:R,ERE,1: ...(...)... --end%` where `%msg%` is the property used as input for a regexp `R`, extended regexp `ERE`, keep only capture group 1, followed by the regexp pattern which has a capture group `()`, with the replacer ended by `--end`.

Since this template always adds the word `HOST01` to the message you should only use it if the message actually contains `localhost`, so
edit the action where you log the message to test for this, eg:

```
:msg, contains, " localhost "      -/var/log/test.log; newmsg
```

Note the use of the template at the end: `; newmsg`.

---

You can use templates when sending to a remote too, eg:

```
action(type="omfwd" 
 Target="server.example.net"
 Port="10514"
 Protocol="tcp"
 Template="newmsg"
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the message, unfortunately it only works in the process of receiving data, not in sending it as I plan to use it. Thank you again, greetings.

Comment: You can use templates when sending to remotes. I've included an example in rainer script form (you can read about it [here](http://www.rsyslog.com/tag/tag/) ).

Comment: The @meuh 's example is quite useful. There are so many questions asked on Internet how to modify the raw/forwarded rsyslog message, and this is the only one I could find.